# storing links of a site in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am trying to store the links that I scrape from a site in a non binary tree. The links are laid out hierarchically (obviously). The question is how do I generate the tree ? I mean, how am I going to work my way through the pages provided by the link so that I know who is who's child.

For now I can get the first and the second level of links, but have no idea how to go from here besides that I have to recursively have to build it and have a way to stop when I get to a leaf (which I have).

What I was thinking was something like (code in Python):

```
def buildTree(root):
for node in root.children:
    if <end condition here>:
        continue
    else:
        nodes = getNodes(urllib2.urlopen(node.url).read())
        node.addChildren(nodes)
        buildTree(node)
```

where root and nodes are a user defined **Node** class

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand you correctly, you basically want to do crawl through an entire site and create a family tree of all of the links that originate from a parent link?  You're on the right track, but it sounds like you have two things that are confusing you -- what data structure to store the information in, and how to write the recursive function.  What do you want to do with the data afterward?  Visualize it?  Serialize it?

Comment: You're right, I want to go through the entire site and create the tree. The recursive function I think I got it, but I am not sure about the data structure, whether a tree is good for this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the links in a site are not a tree, but a **graph**. You should have a Page object, which is identified by a URL, and a Link object, which points from one page to another (and Page A can point to page B, while page B is pointing to Page A, making it a graph, instead of a tree).

Scanning algorithm pseudo-code:

```
process_page(current_page):
    for each link on the current_page: 
    if target_page is not already in your graph:
        create a Page object to represent target_page
        add it to to_be_scanned set
    add a link from current_page to target_page

scan_website(start_page)
    create Page object for start_page
    to_be_scanned = set(start_page)
    while to_be_scanned is not empty:
        current_page = to_be_scanned.pop()
        process_page(current_page)
```

Comment: Yes, it's totally a graph and not a tree. Thanks!